# Couldn't get push token for device. Check that your FCM configuration is valid

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I want to resolve this problem getting a push token

Error: Couldn't get push token for device. Check that your FCM configuration is valid

In my react native app I implemented Expo permissions and notification but nothing happened. I'm using node js and expo push notifications service.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed login into expo cli:
Check here:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7831#issuecomment-613647709.